# input data autônomo javascript

Tags: javascript, html

eu criei uma pagina de cadastro poerem a função do java serias acoplar o simbolo "/" .
exemplo digitando 20 o java acoplava "/" => 20/ digitando mais 2 dígitos => 20/12/ filtrando para o padrão data 20/13/2017 . mas no apos digitar o mês nada aconteci. o que tem de errado ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<font color="orange" size="4">Data:<font><p></p>
<input type="text" required maxlength="10" id="data" onkeyup="datajs()" placeholder="dia/mes/ano" />

<script>
    function datajs(){

    data = document.getElementById("data").value;
    var dia = data.substr(0,2);
    var mes = data.substr(2,3);
    var ano = data.substr(5,4);
    var data1 = data.substr(2,1);
    var data2 = data.substr(5,1);
    if (data1 != "/") {
        if( data.length >= 3 ) {
              if( data.length <= 4 ) {
                  document.forms[0].data.value = dia+'/'+mes;
       }
   }
}



    if(data2 != "/") {
        if( data.length > 5 ) {
            if( data.length <= 10 ) {
            document.forms[0].data.value = dia+mes+'/'+ano;
           }
        }
      }
    }
 </script>

 <style>
 #data {
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Difícil entender a questão. Elabore melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Denilson, já usei isso mas com jQuery e Masked, bem prático e lhe servirá para varios outras formatações de texto, datas e etc...

Baixe o jQuery e o Masked no próprio site do jQuery.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <font color="orange" size="4">Data:<font><p></p>
  <input type="text" required maxlength="10" id="data" placeholder="dia/mes/ano" />

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#data").mask("99/99/9999");
    });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```